# Populate df column on median of a subset from another df

Tags: python, dataframe, slice

I have two dataframes: one representing blocks of samples (df1) and another that has performance values for multiple samples in a time series (df2). I would like to populate df1 by slicing df2 using a dictionary and calculating the median. While I could brute force it through a for loop, I would like to learn the more appropriate approach. I feel like df.apply() should be able to do it, but I run into a "'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed" error.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=['qb','qb_median'])
df1.qb=['qb1','qb2']

df1
Out[76]: 
    qb qb_median
0  qb1       NaN
1  qb2       NaN

df2=pd.DataFrame({'sample':['A','B','C','D','E','F'],'x':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

df2
Out[78]: 
  sample  x
0      A  1
1      B  2
2      C  3
3      D  4
4      E  5
5      F  6

sets={'qb1':['A','B','C'],'qb2':['D','E','F']}
```

I would like to populate df1 such that

```
    qb qb_median
0  qb1       2
1  qb2       5
```

What I thought might work was something like:

```
def get_med(q, lookup_df):
     return lookup_df.loc[lookup_df['sample'].isin(sets[q])]['x'].median()

df1['qb_median']=df1.apply(lambda x: get_med(df1.qb, df2), axis=1)
```

I've also tried variations of:

```
df1['qb_median']=df2.loc[df2['sample'].isin(sets[df1.qb_median])]['x'].median()
```

I feel like I'm 'right there', but just can't make it work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, hope it helps.

```
df1.set_index('qb',inplace=True)

for qb in df1.index.values:
    qb_median = df2[df2['sample'].isin(sets[qb])]['x'].median()
    df1['qb_median'][qb] = qb_median
```

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of in line with the brute force approach I alluded to. Fine for a few lines, but I didn't think it's in keeping with the whole "don't iterate over dataframes" ideology. While this specific application (abbreviated for the example) only has 6 rows, I was asking more for the time when I have to do something similar over a much larger data set.

Comment: I had edited the answer to use looping over the qb

Comment: Thanks for your comments and edit. I had assumed a for loop when you first responded. However, it does not quite address the question I'm interested in: Is there a better way to do this action without looping over the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a new column, using masks to know the value of the column
and then use groupby? The first part is still kinda-loopy but the groupby to get the mean is more pythonic

```
df2['qbgroup'] = ''
df2.loc[((df2['sample']=='A') | (df2['sample']=='B') | (df2['sample']=='C')), 'qbgroup'] = 'qb1'
df2.loc[((df2['sample']=='D') | (df2['sample']=='E') | (df2['sample']=='F')), 'qbgroup'] = 'qb2'
foo = df2.groupby(df2['qbgroup']).mean()
```